# Cakephp 2 user have multiple group access

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, acl, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

How to change cakephp concept user belongsTo Group, to user hasMany Group,
apart make new table called users_groups, and what should I change to make my user really have access to many groups that user have?

Answer (score 0):

**Make Things Simple:**

In such scenario you already needed three tables.

**Users table**

- id
- name
- phone

**Groups**

- id
- group(title)

**User_Groups**

- id
- user_id
- group_id

As you need relations like user has many groups then you need extra table  which at least should include foreign key like user_id, and group_id.So don't hesitate to add extra table for making things simple.

Comment: I understand about the extra table, but about group access for user what should I do ? now the acl of cakephp have three tables, aco, aro, aros_acos, whether those are same tables ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be using 3 tables, and then a [HasAndBelongsToMany](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) relationship over the Users_Groups. Users HABTM Groups